# Underline Textview

Tags: android, textview, underline

Just a quick question:
Do you know why i can do that:

```
pnrCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pnr);
        SpannableString pnrContent = new SpannableString("PNR: ");
        pnrContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, pnrContent.length(), 0);
        pnrCode.setText(pnrContent + BookingSettings.getBookingSegment().substring(0, 6));
```

The text is not underlined.

Whereas, if i do only that:

```
  pnrCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pnr);
            SpannableString pnrContent = new SpannableString("PNR: ");
            pnrContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, pnrContent.length(), 0);
            pnrCode.setText(pnrContent);
```

The text is underlined.

I have to create two textview ?
Do you know another solution ?

Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have to create two textview ?

No.

`pnrContent + BookingSettings.getBookingSegment().substring(0, 6)` is probably going to give you a `String` back, as I believe the `+` operator will convert both sides to `String` objects, then perform the concatenation. Hence, you will lose your formatting.

Instead, use `new SpannableString("PNR: "+ BookingSettings.getBookingSegment().substring(0, 6));`, and set the length of the `UnderlineSpan` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But in fact, i only want to underline "PNR: " ! Your solution underline the entire string, no?

Comment: To underline just the "PNR:" you should set the span only for the first 4 characters in this way:  pnrContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 4, 0);